# How to wait for multiple firebase queries to finish before executing a task?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to figure out how to delete all saved User's data, and once that data is deleted, Signout the user and delete their account when `deleteUserAccount()` is called.

Right now, when the User presses the "Delete Account" button, their account gets deleted, but the data still remains on firebase because the completion handler gets called before the `deleteAllUserTicketData()` function has enough time to execute the query and delete the appropriate documents.

How can I wait for the queries to execute and all the documents to get deleted before executing the completion handler in order to sign the user out and delete their account?

```
 func deleteAllUserTicketData(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

        let group = DispatchGroup()

        group.enter()
        self.rootWsrCollection?.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userIdRef).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else { return }
            for wsr in snapshot.documents{
                print("Deleting WSR: \(wsr)")
                wsr.reference.delete()
            }
            group.leave()
        }

        group.enter()
        self.rootExerciseCollection?.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userIdRef).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else { return }
            for exercise in snapshot.documents {
                print("Deleting Exercise: \(exercise)")
                exercise.reference.delete()
            }
            group.leave()
        }

        group.enter()
        self.rootWorkoutsCollection?.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userIdRef).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else { return }
            for workout in snapshot.documents {
                print("Deleting Workout: \(workout)")
                workout.reference.delete()
            }
            group.leave()
        }

        group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global()) { [weak self] in
            self?.workoutsCollection.daysCollection.removeAll()
            print("Calling Notify Method")
            completion()
        }

    }

    //This method will only delete the user from the Firestore, but will not delete the User Auth credentials.
    func deleteUserFromFirestore(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.rootUserCollection?.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userIdRef).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else { return }
            for user in snapshot.documents {
                print("Deleting User: \(user)")
                user.reference.delete()
            }
            completion()
        }
    }

    func deleteUserAccount() {
        deleteAllUserTicketData {
            print("First Completion is called")
            self.deleteUserFromFirestore {
                print("Second Completion is called")
                Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete()
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It's a bit dangerous deleting the user's documents before deleting the user's account, don't you think? What if only a portion of the documents are deleted? Then you never reach completion which means the account isn't deleted and the user can still sign in and possibly not be able to do anything in the app if core documents are missing. Have you considered creating a cloud function that is automatically called when a user account is deleted? There is a built-in trigger function for that. Let the user delete the account so they can't sign in and then delete all of their documents.

Comment: Look into `async await` Firebase has started provided compatible methods

Comment: I tried implementing the solution that @Neklas had suggested, but to no avail. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `DispatchGroup` to wait for all async then trigger when they all finish. If you `enter()` 5 times, you also need to `leave()` 5 times. You need to **balance** the `leave()` with `enter()`.
If you call `leave()` more than `enter()`, it will crash because of unbalanced call.

And, please do not use addSnapShotListener if you don't need to make a real-time observer. Use this instead https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Here is your updated logic [1st Update]

```
func deleteAllUserTicketData(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    
    // Inner function
    func deleteWithWaiting(snapShot: QuerySnapshot?) {
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            dispatchGroup.leave() // leave 1 after fetching documents
            return
        }
        
        for document in snapshot.documents {
            dispatchGroup.enter() // enter 2 before async delete
            document.delete() { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error removing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document successfully removed!")
                }
                dispatchGroup.leave() // leave 2 after async delete
            }
        }
        dispatchGroup.leave() // leave 1 after fetching documents
    }
    
    // PLEASE use the .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    // instead of .addSnapshotListener {(querySnapshot, err) in
    // You just need to fetch data once, not making a new event listener, though it only triggers once.
    
    dispatchGroup.enter() // enter 1 before fetching documents
    self.rootWsrCollection?.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userIdRef).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        deleteWithWaiting(snapShot: querySnapshot)
    }
    
    dispatchGroup.enter() // enter 1 before fetching documents
    self.rootExerciseCollection?.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userIdRef).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        deleteWithWaiting(snapShot: querySnapshot)
    }
    
    dispatchGroup.enter() // enter 1 before fetching documents
    self.rootWorkoutsCollection?.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userIdRef).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        deleteWithWaiting(snapShot: querySnapshot)
    }
    
    // When no waiting item remains (all entered and left), this block will be triggered on queue, in this case, is it Global queue (like background thread
    // So if you need to update UI from this, you need to switch to Main Queue or DispatchQueue.main.async { }
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global()) { [weak self] in
        // refer to self with a weak reference to avoid retain cycle, prevent memory leak
        self?.workoutsCollection.daysCollection.removeAll()
        completion()
    }
}

func deleteUserFromFirestore(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    
    dispatchGroup.enter() // enter 1 before fetching documents
    self.rootUserCollection?.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userIdRef).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            dispatchGroup.leave() // leave 1 after fetching documents
            return
        }
        
        for document in snapshot.documents {
            dispatchGroup.enter() // enter 2 before async delete
            document.delete() { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error removing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document successfully removed!")
                }
                dispatchGroup.leave() // leave 2 after async delete
            }
        }
        dispatchGroup.leave() // leave 1 after fetching documents
    }
    
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global()) {
        completion() // now we finished the deleting
    }
}

func deleteUserAccount() {
    // Swich to Background Thread to perform big-calculation or long-waiting task
    DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
        self?.deleteAllUserTicketData {
            self?.deleteUserFromFirestore {
                Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete()
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    // Update your new UI state here
                    self?.doSomething()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually didn't work for me. It performs the operations in order, but not all of the data gets deleted on the backend.

Comment: @RapsIn4 please review your logic instead of unaccepting my answer man. This is what I took from Firebase Doc. I updated it based on your code for how to wait.

You can see my comment: // Suppose that delete() is a success. If it is not a success right after this call this is your problem. 

Let me update it a bit for you.

Comment: I updated answer, please check it again.

Comment: @RapsIn4 I updated my logic. Change it to leave() after finishing async delete